# При нажатии на ссылку появляется свой блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку появлялся свой блок?

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="">Ссылка 1</a>
<div>Блок 1</div>
<a href="">Ссылка 2</a>
<div>Блок 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Вариант jQuery*

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).next().toggle('slow');
  return false;
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Ссылка 1</a>
<div>Блок 1</div>
<a href="">Ссылка 2</a>
<div>Блок 2</div>
```

*Вариант на чистом JavaScript*

```js
function look(elemId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  elem.style.display === "none" ?
    elem.style.display = "block" : elem.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="look('link1'); return false;" href="#">Ссылка 1</a>
<div id="link1" class="div" style="display: none;">Блок 1</div>
<a onclick="look('link2'); return false;" href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
<div id="link2" class="div" style="display: none;">Блок 2</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
}

.block:target{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#block1">Ссылка 1</a>
<div class="block" id="block1">Блок 1</div>
<a href="#block2">Ссылка 2</a>
<div class="block" id="block2">Блок 2</div>
```